When I try to set up Next.js app it shows me NPM ERR
When trying to set up a new app using npx create-next-app@latest it shows me the error:
npm ERR! code EJSONPARSE
npm ERR! path C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_npx\cc2145a2fe1558fa/package.json
npm ERR! JSON.parse Unexpected token '', ""... is not valid JSON while parsing ''
npm ERR! JSON.parse Failed to parse JSON data.
npm ERR! JSON.parse Note: package.json must be actual JSON, not just JavaScript.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2024-04-21T17_19_55_143Z-debug-0.log

How can I fix this?
I tried cleaning up of cache in npm module and restarted the whole VS Code setup and after that I deleted and re-installed VS Code to solve the issue it won't work


package.json must be actual JSON, not just JavaScript

Can you show your package.json file?
Looks like you just made some simple mistake, try to validate it with:
https://jsonlint.com

oh wait its npx command my bad,
looks like cache is still there for you:
npm ERR! path C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_npx\cc2145a2fe1558fa/package.json
try to delete this folder manually C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\npm-cache

thank you when i tried it worked
